# Android Error tracing in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am developing Android app in eclipse with Android SDK 2.3, but i am unable to see the errors like we see in java or .net, there are no run time errors tracing, if there is some error i have to place alerts there to check it, where as compiler does not place any error in its window. Its quite strange that it gives compile time error but no run time error. Please help.

Thanks
Atif

Comment: are you talking about logcat?

Comment: i wana see run times error on console, system.out.println also does not work

Comment: look the logcat. It gives all the information of runtime activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Window->Show View->Other.., and select Android->LogCat. This is the running system trace. I believe this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So first thing about android is, you will not be able to look your output details in console as your java or .net shows. As you might know emulator is what is considered to be your output window. And in order to find compile time errors eclipse makes it easy by highlighting your mistakes instantly. And as you have asked for, to look at your runtime errors android uses a special view called **Logcat**. This is were you will be listed out with all the runtime details of android. And as you have said that you are not able to view even `System.out.println` messages not being viewed, you might find it a bit strange but  actually android does print these mesages in **Logcat** for you. So as the user [sparkymat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534734/sparkymat) has suggested follow the steps and you are done.